# How to resolve KeyError: 'System.AssignedTo' of a query with Python REST API?

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am doing a work item extraction that requires all the information and in fact the code is fine because it does extract all the information along with the Assigned To

```
wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()

def get_TC_from_query(query):
    query_wiql = Wiql(query=query)
    results = wit_client.query_by_wiql(query_wiql).work_items
    work_items = (wit_client.get_work_item(int(result.id)) for result in results)
    print_work_items(work_items)

def print_work_items(work_items):
    
    for work_item in work_items:
         
                print(
                    "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(
                        work_item.id,
                        work_item.fields["System.WorkItemType"],
                        work_item.fields["System.AssignedTo"],
                        work_item.fields["System.Title"],
                    )
                )
```

This is how I do the query

```
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()
get_projects_response = core_client.get_projects()
for project in get_projects_response.value:
        query = "SELECT" +\
                    "[System.Id]," +\
                    "[System.WorkItemType]," +\
                    "[System.Title]," +\
                    "[System.AssignedTo]," +\
                    "[System.State]," +\
                    "[System.Tags]" +\
                    "From WorkItems " +\
        "Where [Work Item Type] = 'Task' " +\
        "and [System.TeamProject] = '" + project.name + "' "
        get_TC_from_query(query)
```

It extracts a part well and then the following error appears

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-452da778444a> in <module>
     12         "Where [Work Item Type] = 'Task' " +\
     13         "and [System.TeamProject] = '" + project.name + "' "
---> 14         get_TC_from_query(query)

<ipython-input-44-413ec27c98f8> in get_TC_from_query(query)
      5     results = wit_client.query_by_wiql(query_wiql).work_items
      6     work_items = (wit_client.get_work_item(int(result.id)) for result in results)
----> 7     print_work_items(work_items)

<ipython-input-32-5a881133f6d0> in print_work_items(work_items)
      7                         work_item.id,
      8                         work_item.fields["System.WorkItemType"],
----> 9                         work_item.fields["System.AssignedTo"],
     10                         work_item.fields["System.Title"],
     11                     )

KeyError: 'System.AssignedTo'
```

I hope you can help me to solve this problem, thank you.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you might use `work_item.fields.get("System.AssignedTo")` instead to avoid the KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is an empty field `System.AssignedTo` in one of the work items. You have to check field availability in `work_item.fields` before using it.